# where and orWhere issue for same column data in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, where-clause

My table is look like

| id | locale | language_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bn | Bengali |
| 2 | en | English |
| 3 | hi | Hindi |
| 4 | ar | Arabic |
| 5 | ja_jp | Japanese |

My query is -

**$locale** = 'bn';

**$languages** = Language::orderBy('locale','ASC')->where('locale',$locale)->orWhere('locale','en')->get();

I want to show - 
***1. If locale='en'*** 
Show only English (en) data 
***2. If locale='bn'*** 
Show only Bengali (bn) data 
***3. If locale='xyz'*** 
Show only English (en) data because 'xyz' does not exist in table. 
***4. If locale='xyz' and the locale 'en' (English) does not exist in the table*** 
Show the Empty [];

1,3,4 point is show accurately which I want but I face problem in 2 no points, when i set 'bn' (or others except 'en') this time it retrieves 'bn' and 'en' both data but I want only 'bn' data of locale. How to solve ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to retrieve a collection or just a single model?

If always only single model then

```
$locale = 'bn';

$language = Language::where('locale', $locale)->first() ?? Language::where('locale', 'en')->first() ?? null;
```